# why Threads_connected falls down automatically in some cases

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, magento

How can I monitoring, when Threads_connected increase from which place(files) or when it decrease, because some of cases it dose not fall down automatically in our production server and we are getting to max connection error there, So i need to identify issues in which files has problem,  My site in magento 1.9 and max_connections=151 so i want to know what the ideal count for that and how can i monitoring ?

Comment: Create event which gets this parameter and saves it into some table (with grnularity of 1 sec, for example). Then analyze this data with conjunction to general log and search for a correlation between issues and value increasing.

Comment: What is Threads_created, Threads_cached, thread_cache_size?

Comment: Threads_created = 4921
Threads_cached =  1
thread_cache_size = 9

Comment: `thread_cache_size` value is too low. Increase it with accuracy (with the step of not more than 10%), wait some hours, then check the values again. Repeat until `Threads_created` is **slightly** greater than `Threads_cached`.

Comment: I have checked various time in my production server but always getting same count there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are a few long queries that lock lots of things, then runs for a while.  Meanwhile, other connections come and try to get at the locked things, but get stalled.

If you are using MyISAM, switch to InnoDB.

Set long_query_time to 1 and turn on the slowlog.  After a while, it will catch the naughty query.  Show us the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) that it touches.

Comment: @DarshanTecStub - Screenshots are not appreciated on this forum.  Having to sign up to see them makes them more of a turn-off.

Comment: When I run **SHOW CREATE TABLE sales_flat_order_item** command it give long result there, here I can't able to post that data because of comment area validation. So how can I display that table ?

Comment: @DarshanTecStub - Go through the tutorial so you get an extra 100 Reputation.  Then you can (I think) edit your Question.